# Why are there blank spaces between my CSV between each row?

Tags: python, scrapy

When I run this code in my commandline; scrapy crawl indeed -o items.csv, I receive an output with blank spaces between each row. See image. How do i solve this?

[image]

```
import scrapy

class IndeedSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'indeed'
    allowed_domains = ['indeed.nl']
    start_urls = ['https://www.indeed.nl/vacatures?q=developer&l=']

    def parse(self, response):
        jobs =response.xpath('//div[@class="  row  result" or 
        @class="lastRow  row  result"]')
        for job in jobs:
            jobtitle = job.xpath('h2/a/@title').extract_first()
            company = 
            job.xpath('.//span[@class="company"]/text()').extract_first()

            yield{
                'jobtitle': jobtitle, 
                'company': company}
```

Comment: I don't use scrapy, but where are you writing to a csv?

Comment: In the anaconda prompt I use: scrapy crawl indeed -o items.csv

Comment: If this is on Windows, you'll need to pass `newline=''` when you open the file in write mode (for Python 3) or open in `wb` mode in python 2. That's if you're using the CSV module somewhere outside of this code.

Comment: like @roganjosh said, `newline=''` is the option you need to pass (or at least usually fixes the problem), but I'm not sure where you give this to scrapy

Comment: This is a bug that's been in scrapy for a while, and there's a PR fixing it on github, but the people in charge are just not merging it (apparently because the author didn't include tests, but it doesn't actually change anything, so...). If you want, you can just take a look at what was changed in https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/3039